# Magento Multi-Site displaying global title suffix in Bing

Tags: seo, title, bing

If you [search for the term 'StyleStalker' on Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=StyleStalker&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=stylestalker&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=d94b860d786d4c8da910069786e80067) it shows up as

```
Shop - StyleStalker - Eighth Story
```

The site is setup as a Magento multi-store which contains [StyleStalker](http://www.stylestalker.com) and [Eight Story](http://www.8thstory.com)

The default site is setup in System -> Configuration -> Design

```
Default Title: Eighth Story
Title Suffix:  - Eighth Story
```

[image]

But each store configuration is set

```
Eighth Story
    Default Title: Eighth Story
    Title Suffix:  - Eighth Story
```

[image]

```
StyleStalker
    Default Title: StyleStalker
    Title Suffix:  - StyleStalker
```

[image]

Why does Bing display the store specific and the global setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your title in Bing as: `Eighth Story - StyleStalker`, although a bit different, still the same issue. I think what's happening here is Bing as adding to your title, as the title you have defined is quite short, simply `StyleStalker`.

Bing and Google will often add to page titles if they are quite short, as often a short title doesn't really give enough information, which yours doesn't. `StyleStalker` doesn't give any information to the user about what the site is about when dispayed in the SERPS. So Google and Bing try and add info they might find on the page, or in links pointing to the page to try and make the title more informative, (quite often adding what they believe is the company name) but sometimes they can add the wrong content, which doesn't really help matters.

Looking in the source code of your home page you have `Eighth Story` defined as the og:site_name:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Eighth Story">
```

I'd take a guess that is where Bing is pulling the `Eighth Story` from, thinking its the site name, as defined as such in the og tags and appending it to the title.

To stop this happening, I'd first place the correct name of the site in the OG tags and for each page on your site I would create slightly longer, more informative titles.  Your home page title could be something like:

```
Cutting-Edge Womens Clothes & Fashion From Stylestalker
```

You can use a tool such as [Snippet Optimizer](http://www.seomofo.com/snippet-optimizer.html) to help craft titles that will correctly display in Google's Search results